# The Address data detector type is not supported on iOS versions prior to 4.0

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

Has anyone encountered this warming in Xcode 3.2.4 before?

ViewController.xib:4: warning: The Address data detector type is not supported on iOS versions prior to 4.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, what it is saying is true. :)  It is only a warning, which means your app will run fine on iOS < 4.0, they will just not have the Address data detector.

Comment: lol so I don't have to worry about it?  I have been struggling for the last 3 days on a memory problem in my code - so I must be over analyzing ;-)

Comment: You might be suffering from apophenia. :P  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apophenia