# warning: Attribute Unavailable: Addresses Detection on iOS versions prior to 4.0

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

Does anyone know what this means:

.../...ViewController.xib: warning: Attribute Unavailable: Addresses Detection on iOS versions prior to 4.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check below SO post

[The Address data detector type is not supported on iOS versions prior to 4.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4097631/the-address-data-detector-type-is-not-supported-on-ios-versions-prior-to-4-0)